# Mapbox marker cluster with custom icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mapbox

I am trying to have my icons cluster so they don't just bunch up on top of each other. Mapbox provides some example on how to use clustering icons but I can't figure out how they are getting the icons/information onto the map.

here is their code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Clusters with custom cluster icons</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.1/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.1/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-markercluster/v0.4.0/leaflet.markercluster.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-markercluster/v0.4.0/MarkerCluster.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-markercluster/v0.4.0/MarkerCluster.Default.css' rel='stylesheet' />

<div id='map'></div>

<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoib21uaXVzbm93IiwiYSI6ImFlZ0pNSXMifQ.VNyOy9GaRZ1cAS2nDTp3tw';
// Here we don't use the second argument to map, since that would automatically
// load in non-clustered markers from the layer. Instead we add just the
// backing tileLayer, and then use the featureLayer only for its data.
var map = L.mapbox.map('map')
    .setView([40.73, -74.011], 13)
    .addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.streets'));

// Since featureLayer is an asynchronous method, we use the `.on('ready'`
// call to only use its marker data once we know it is actually loaded.
L.mapbox.featureLayer('examples.map-h61e8o8e').on('ready', function(e) {
    // The clusterGroup gets each marker in the group added to it
    // once loaded, and then is added to the map
    var clusterGroup = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({
      // The iconCreateFunction takes the cluster as an argument and returns
      // an icon that represents it. We use L.mapbox.marker.icon in this
      // example, but you could also use L.icon or L.divIcon.
      iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
        return L.mapbox.marker.icon({
          // show the number of markers in the cluster on the icon.
          'marker-symbol': cluster.getChildCount(),
          'marker-color': '#422'
        });
      }
    });
    e.target.eachLayer(function(layer) {
        clusterGroup.addLayer(layer);
    });
    map.addLayer(clusterGroup);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It would appear they are importing their map data in this line here

"L..mapbox.featureLayer('examples.map-h61e8o8e').on('ready', function(e)"

Because if I replace 'examples.map-h61e8o8e' with my own map I lose all the icons. But mine don't show up.

So I can't figure out how they are pulling this information and. All that being said this is MY current code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Custom marker icons</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.6/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.6/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.menu-ui {
  background:#A2A19F;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:50px;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-110px;
  z-index:1;
  border-radius:3px;
  width:auto;
  }
  .menu-ui a {
    font-size:22px;
    color:#fff;
    display:table-cell;
    padding:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    }
    .menu-ui a:first-child {
      border-radius:3px 3px 0 0;
      }
    .menu-ui a:last-child {
      border:none;
      border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;
      }
    .menu-ui a:hover {
      background:#f8f8f8;
      color:#404040;
      }
    .menu-ui a.active,
    .menu-ui a.active:hover {
      background:#DB3E3A;
      color:#FFF;
      }
  
.popup {
  text-align:center;
  
  }
.popup .slideshow .image        { display:none; }
.popup .slideshow .image.active { transition: opacity 2s linear;display:block; }
.popup .slideshow img {
  width:100%;
  
  }
.popup .slideshow .caption {
  background:none;
  padding:10px;
  color:white;
  }
.popup .cycle {

  padding:10px 0 20px;
  }
  .popup .cycle a.prev { float:left; }
  .popup .cycle a.next { float:right; }
li.menu-item {
   margin:0 0 10px 0; 
   
}
</style>

<nav class='menu-ui'>

  <a href='#' class='active' data-filter='Development'>Development</a><a href='#' data-filter='Land'>Land</a>
</nav>

<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-markercluster/v0.4.0/leaflet.markercluster.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-markercluster/v0.4.0/MarkerCluster.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-markercluster/v0.4.0/MarkerCluster.Default.css' rel='stylesheet' />

<div id='map'></div>
<!-- jQuery is required for this example. -->
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>
<script src="/mapbox.js/assets/data/realworld.388.js"></script>
<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoib21uaXVzbm93IiwiYSI6ImFlZ0pNSXMifQ.VNyOy9GaRZ1cAS2nDTp3tw';
var southWest = L.latLng(21.284438,-131.265625),
    northEast = L.latLng(54.606163, -62.929688),
    bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'coltonneil.3dc5d18e', {
    // set that bounding box as maxBounds to restrict moving the map
    // see full maxBounds documentation:
    // http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-maxbounds
    maxBounds: bounds,
    maxZoom: 16,
    minZoom: 5
});
// zoom the map to that bounding box
map.fitBounds(bounds);


var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer('coltonneil.3dc5d18e').on('ready', function(e) {
    // The clusterGroup gets each marker in the group added to it
    // once loaded, and then is added to the map
    var clusterGroup = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({
      // The iconCreateFunction takes the cluster as an argument and returns
      // an icon that represents it. We use L.mapbox.marker.icon in this
      // example, but you could also use L.icon or L.divIcon.
      iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
        return L.mapbox.marker.icon({
          // show the number of markers in the cluster on the icon.
          'marker-symbol': cluster.getChildCount(),
          'marker-color': '#422'
        });
      }
    });
    e.target.eachLayer(function(layer) {
        clusterGroup.addLayer(layer);
    });
    map.addLayer(clusterGroup);
});
var cluster = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({
    iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
        return new L.DivIcon({ html: '<b>' + cluster.getChildCount() + '</b>' });
    }
});
var geoJson = [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-80.190583, 25.767619]
    },
    "properties": {
        "title": "BRICKELL WORLD PLAZA",
//this should let the button code know whether this is a development or a //land catagory, IT IS CASE SENSATIVE!!
   "Development":true,
   "Land":false,
        "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/9sxqWaV.png",
            "iconSize": [35, 22], // size of the icon
            "iconAnchor": [22, 27], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            "popupAnchor": [0, -25], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            "className": "dot"
   
        },
  'images': [
          ['http://i.imgur.com/vQgol04.jpg','<p><b>Location: Miami, Florida</b></p>More than just another development. Brickell World Plaza is a benchmark for Miami’s future.<center>Visit <a href="http://www.brickellworldplaza.com/"> 600 Brickell.</a></center>'],
          ['http://i.imgur.com/wCyKfJs.jpg',' The soaring 600 Brickell office tower is unmatched in its future-smart, Eco-friendly design and services.'],
          ['http://i.imgur.com/kvSRm4L.jpg','The 30,000-square-foot, tree-shaded Plaza will enrich the community for generations to come.']
        ]
  
    }
},{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-82.356899, 29.633012]
    },
    "properties": {
        "title": "THE BARTRAM",
   "Development":true,
   "Land":false,
        "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/9sxqWaV.png",
           "iconSize": [35, 22], // size of the icon
            "iconAnchor": [22, 27], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            "popupAnchor": [0, -25], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            "className": "dot"
   
        },
  'images': [
          ['http://i.imgur.com/P6qbN8I.jpg','<p><b>Location: Gainesville, Florida</b></p>The Bartram is an environmentally friendly, Class A luxury, resort-style apartment complex, located at 2337 SW Archer Road in Gainesville Florida.<center>Visit <a href="http://thebartram.com/"> The Bartram.</a></center>'],
          ['http://i.imgur.com/yDLxcqI.jpg','The Bartram offers the ideal luxury living experience. Our property consists of 334 spacious apartments that offer modern design and relaxation.'],
          ['http://i.imgur.com/tcroFTJ.jpg','Once residents leave their apartments they have access to a handful of amenities which include resort-style swimming pools, our Meditation Garden, the Clubhouse, which features complimentary Wi-Fi access, and our two-story fitness center.']
               ]
  
    }
},{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-84.650528, 34.610110]
    },
    "properties": {
        'title': 'CARTER\'S LAKE',
   "Development":true,
   "Land":false,
        "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/9sxqWaV.png",
            "iconSize": [35, 22], // size of the icon
            "iconAnchor": [22, 27], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            "popupAnchor": [0, -25], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            "className": "dot"
   
        },
  'images': [
          ['http://i.imgur.com/GwbPN51.png','<p><b>Location: Ellijay, Georgia</b></p>This newly planned and gated community of 350 lots opened in 2004 on Carter’s Lake in Glimer county, Georgia.'],
          ['http://i.imgur.com/GwbPN51.png','The lots range in size from one to two acres each and offer some of the most spectacular views of the lake and the mountains of North Georgia.'],
          ['http://i.imgur.com/GwbPN51.png','Foram Group was the original co-developer of this project and is currently the asset manager for all lots in phase V of the development.']
        ]
  
    }
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-81.052371, 32.043918]
    },
    "properties": {
        'title': 'LAUREL VIEW',
   "Development":true,
   "Land":false,
        "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/9sxqWaV.png",
            "iconSize": [35, 22], // size of the icon
            "iconAnchor": [22, 27], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            "popupAnchor": [0, -25], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            "className": "dot"
   
        },
  'images': [
          ['http://i.imgur.com/KM3zmmP.gif','<p><b>Location: Savannah, Georgia</b></p>Laurel View is located just 30 miles south of historic downtown Savannah at the Midway interchange at 1-95, at Exit 76.'],
          ['http://i.imgur.com/xf4xz5M.jpg','The property is 5,000 acres with more than ten miles of pristine marsh and deep water frontage on Jones Creek and Laurel View River.'],
          ['http://i.imgur.com/GwbPN51.png','Laurel View will be a complete sustainable community with marina golf, residential and commercial sites on some of the most spectacular land in the coastal south.']
        ]
  
    }
},{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-81.247057, 32.115481]
    },
    "properties": {
        'title': 'POOLER, GA',
   "Development":true,
   "Land":false,
        "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/9sxqWaV.png",
            "iconSize": [35, 22], // size of the icon
            "iconAnchor": [22, 27], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            "popupAnchor": [0, -25], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            "className": "dot"
   
        },
  'images': [
          ['http://i.imgur.com/JyIuLMm.jpg','<p><b>Location: Pooler, Georgia</b></p>Over 900 acres of commercial and residential land located near the Parkway Interchange in Savannah Georgia.'],
          ['http://i.imgur.com/4t1xF2w.jpg','Ready to build lots with highway access less than 1/4 mile away.'],
          ['http://i.imgur.com/gmx8LVL.jpg','Lake front property is also available at our Pooler developments.']
        ]
  
    }
},{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-81.146635, 32.788518]
    },
    "properties": {
        'title': 'ESTILL FARM',
      "Development":false,
   "Land":true,
        "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/9sxqWaV.png",
           "iconSize": [35, 22], // size of the icon
            "iconAnchor": [22, 27], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            "popupAnchor": [0, -25], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            "className": "dot"
   
        },
  'images': [
          ['http://i.imgur.com/GwbPN51.png','<p><b>Location: Estill, South Carolina</b></p>1,000 acres of premium farming land.'],
          ['http://i.imgur.com/GwbPN51.png','Estill farm also offers excellent commercial game hunting opportunities.']
        ]
  
    }
},{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-81.610061, 32.750461]
    },
    "properties": {
        'title': '301 FARM',
      "Development":false,
   "Land":true,
        "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/9sxqWaV.png",
   "iconSize": [35, 22], // size of the icon
            "iconAnchor": [22, 27], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            "popupAnchor": [0, -25], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            "className": "dot"
   
        },
  'images': [
          ['http://i.imgur.com/GwbPN51.png','<p><b>Location: Screven County, Georgia</b></p> 1,000 acres along Highway 301.'],
          ['http://i.imgur.com/GwbPN51.png','Working Row crop with four (4) center pivot irrigation systems.']
        ]
  
    }
},{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-85.118540, 30.927965]
    },
    "properties": {
        'title': 'SPORTING RETREAT / BASCOM',
      "Development":false,
   "Land":true,
        "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/9sxqWaV.png",
            "iconSize": [35, 22], // size of the icon
            "iconAnchor": [22, 27], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            "popupAnchor": [0, -25], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            "className": "dot"
   
        },
  'images': [
          ['http://i.imgur.com/GwbPN51.png','<p><b>Location: Bascom, Georgia</b></p>1,804 acres at the intersection of Country Road 244 and County Road 236 near Hilltonia, Georgia.']
        ]
  
    }
},{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-105.071058, 39.033353]
    },
    "properties": {
        'title': 'TRIPLE J RANCH',
      "Development":false,
   "Land":true,
        "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/9sxqWaV.png",
           "iconSize": [35, 22], // size of the icon
            "iconAnchor": [22, 27], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            "popupAnchor": [0, -25], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            "className": "dot"
   
        },
  'images': [
          ['http://i.imgur.com/ndrLGDs.jpg','<p><b>Location: Garfield County, Colorado</b></p>6100 acres of ranch land located 40 miles west of Aspen, eight miles south of Glenwood Springs and five miles south of New Castle in east-central Garfield County on the south side of Interstate 70.'],
          ['http://i.imgur.com/8rGf6yH.jpg','The property will remain privately owned, but the conservation easement prohibits any future development or subdivision of the property, allowing only for a few agricultural structures.'],
          ['http://i.imgur.com/chZ9oIt.jpg','The easement donation to Aspen Valley Lend Trust, Colorado’s oldest land trust, provides a timely example of a company deeply engaged in ecological practices for the benefit of their bottom line, while keeping an eye on the bigger picture.']
        ]
  
    }
},{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-82.099009, 32.309491]
    },
    "properties": {
        'title': 'ROLLING HILLS',
      "Development":false,
   "Land":true,
        "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/9sxqWaV.png",
           "iconSize": [35, 22], // size of the icon
            "iconAnchor": [22, 27], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            "popupAnchor": [0, -25], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            "className": "dot"
   
        },
  'images': [
          ['http://i.imgur.com/zbXNpCr.jpg','<p><b>Location: Candler County, GA</b></p>Rolling hills acreage information.'],
          ['http://i.imgur.com/rSreZ33.jpg','Rolling hills features.'],
          ['http://i.imgur.com/fuGdhC8.jpg','Rolling hills features.']
        ]
  
    }
},{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-84.490652, 34.508737]
    },
    "properties": {
        'title': 'TALKING ROCK CREEK',
      "Development":false,
   "Land":true,
        "icon": {
            "iconUrl": "http://i.imgur.com/9sxqWaV.png",
           "iconSize": [35, 22], // size of the icon
            "iconAnchor": [22, 27], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            "popupAnchor": [0, -25], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
            "className": "dot"
   
        },
  'images': [
          ['http://i.imgur.com/GwbPN51.png','<p><b>Location: Gilmer County, Georgia</b></p>1,000 acres surrounding Talking Rock Creek in Gilmer County, Georgia.']
        ]
  
    }
}];

// Set a custom icon on each marker based on feature properties.
myLayer.on('layeradd', function(e) {
    var marker = e.layer;
    var feature = marker.feature;
  
    var images = feature.properties.images
    var slideshowContent = '';
 
marker.setIcon(L.icon(feature.properties.icon));
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        var img = images[i];

        slideshowContent += '<div class="image' + (i === 0 ? ' active' : '') + '">' +
                              '<img src="' + img[0] + '" />' +
                              '<div class="caption">' + img[1] + '</div>' +
                            '</div>';
    }

    // Create custom popup content
    var popupContent =  '<div id="' + feature.properties.id + '" class="popup">' +
                            '<h2>' + feature.properties.title + '</h2>' +
                            '<div class="slideshow">' +
                                slideshowContent +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="cycle">' +
                                '<a href="#" class="prev">&laquo; Previous</a>' +
                                '<a href="#" class="next">Next &raquo;</a>' +
        
                            '</div>'
                        '</div>';

    // http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup
    marker.bindPopup(popupContent,{
        closeButton: false,
        minWidth: 400
  
    });
 
});

        
// Add features to the map
myLayer.setGeoJSON(geoJson)
.addTo(map);
myLayer.setFilter(function(f) {
    return f.properties['Development'] === true;
});
//button stuff
$('.menu-ui a').on('click', function() {
    // For each filter link, get the 'data-filter' attribute value.
    var filter = $(this).data('filter');
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    myLayer.setFilter(function(f) {
        // If the data-filter attribute is set to "all", return
        // all (true). Otherwise, filter on markers that have
        // a value set to true based on the filter name.
        return (filter === 'all') ? true : f.properties[filter] === true;
    });
    return false;
});

//end button stuff
$('#map').on('click', '.popup .cycle a', function() {
    var $slideshow = $('.slideshow'),
        $newSlide;

    if ($(this).hasClass('prev')) {
        $newSlide = $slideshow.find('.active').prev();
        if ($newSlide.index() < 0) {
            $newSlide = $('.image').last();
        }
    } else {
        $newSlide = $slideshow.find('.active').next();
        if ($newSlide.index() < 0) {
            $newSlide = $('.image').first();
        }
    }

    $slideshow.find('.active').removeClass('active').hide();
    $newSlide.addClass('active').show();
    return false;
});

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

This is the who map, whereas in their example they seem to only really do the clustering code and they somehow call in the code for the rest of the map.

I've tried going off of their examples to no avail, it's not causing any clustering and unfortunately I know too little about Mapbox/leaflet/jquery to really troubleshoot this issue. I'm not sure if it's my implementation or if my logic is all wrong. So I really need some help. Anything would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: features come from the features you create in a Project. Are you replacing with a Map ID that has features in it? Are you seeing any errors in the console (the browser's development tools)?

Comment: Thanks for the response! No I typed the whole map in notepad++ and the map ID I am using is just a standard map with some color changes to match the website its going in. No errors found. So when you say "features" does that mean i could tie map markers and stuff into a map id instead of having it all written out in one text file?? That would be awesome! How do I create a project so that I can make a feature layer? (is there a tutorial available somewhere I can read?) also does the feature layer support things like galleries and pop up windows that I am using?